# Does POSIX guarantee signals will not be delivered to a partially-initialized thread?

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, posix, signals

On most implementations of POSIX threads, some initialization is required in the newly-created thread before it is in a consistent state able to run application code. This may involve unlocking locks in the thread structure, initializing the "thread register" in implementations that use one, initializing thread-local data (either compiler-level TLS or POSIX thread-specific data), etc. I can't find a clear guarantee that all of this initialization will be finished before the thread can receive any signals; the closest I can find is in 2.4.3:

> The following table defines a set of functions that shall be async-signal-safe. Therefore, applications can invoke them, without restriction, from signal-catching functions:
>
> ...

Presumably, some of these functions (at least `fork`, which has to inspect global state established by the `pthread_atfork` function) depend on the thread being in a consistent, initialized state.

One thing that bothers me is that I've read much of the glibc/nptl source, and cannot find any explicit synchronization to prevent a signal from being handled by the newly-created thread before it's fully initialized. I would expect the thread calling `pthread_create` to block all signals before calling `clone`, and for the new thread to unblock them once initialization is finished, but I can't find any code to that effect nor do I see it in `strace` output.

Comment: Wow, calling `fork()` from a signal handler when `pthread_atfork()` handlers have been set up... You'd *really* have to know what you're doing (and trust your library implementation) for that! Especially if (as is normally the case) the prefork handler grabs a bunch of locks to ensure the data they represent is consistent prior to the fork - any of those locks could in principle be held (or worse, in the process of being acquired) by the thread handling the signal, meaning that the data is irreparably inconsistent (or the process may deadlock!). All good fun :-)

Comment: Well, `fork` is listed as one of the async-signal-safe functions, but I agree that pretty much all of the useful things a `pthread_atfork`-registered function could do are not async-signal-safe. Still there are some valid uses, for instance if your `pthread_atfork` handler simply reinitializes data with fixed values, destroys the controlling mutexes, and initializes new ones (all in the child process of course).

Comment: The more disturbing thing is what happens if a library (not known to be threaded by the calling application; perhaps even dynamically loaded indirectly as a dependency of another library) sets up `pthread_atexit` handlers that are not async-signal-safe. The calling application could expect `fork` to be async-signal-safe (as documented) and call it from a signal handler. I guess what I'm getting at by this thought experiment is that it exposes a flaw in the transparency-of-thread-use-by-libraries model `pthread_atfork` was introduced to create.

Comment: Agree entirely with both your comments - just goes to reinforce my view that you *really* need to know what you're up to before venturing into those murky waters :-)

Comment: Modulo accidentally typing `pthread_atexit` instead of `pthread_atfork` one time.. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I don't think that this is a real answer, but it is to big for a comment)

This is a very interesting question. I've looked through glibc code for `pthread_create` to see how it behaves and unless I'm totally missing something there doesn't seem to be any special behavior to stop this (such as blocking all signals before `clone` and unblocking them in the in the child after some setup {after recording the thread creation time and the C++ catch all exception handler is set up, which happens even in the C code} ).

I was expecting to find a comment that mentioned the possibility of this situation and maybe even a mention of what POSIX said to do (or a mention that it did not say what to do).

Perhaps you should always wrap `pthread_create` in code to block and restore signals, and start all thread functions with an unblock call.

This may very well be an over site in pthreads (or glibc or my understanding of the code).

Comment: The best I can gather is that if signals aren't blocked in the new thread until initialization is finished, the implementation must at least ensure that this does not cause any of the async-signal-safe functions to break. Since `__thread` is not yet standard and thus not part of POSIX, there is of course no requirement that TLS variables are accessible or have their correct values. Perhaps one possible implementation (I haven't yet checked if glibc does this) is to wrap all signal handlers with a handler that finishes thread initialization (if needed) before calling the app's handler.

Comment: I doubt glibc wraps signal handlers like that.  I think that doing so would require it to duplicate the signal handling that the kernel does as well as block and restore signals for each call to `sigaction` to keep from introducing a race condition. I just looked and it does not appear to do this.  It is also a kludgy thing to do, be very difficult, and might require that the regular thread start code be able to recognize that it had been interrupted and shouldn't redo things that had already been done.

Comment: I wouldn't surprised it the old LinuxThreads wrapped signal handlers. It was a hideous hack. :-)

Comment: Linux has the `sa_restorer` function pointer in the kernel's sigaction struct which wraps the bottom half of signal handlers (by returning to the sa_restore code, which is part of glibc, to issue the _I'm_  _through_ system call).  I just learned about this looking into this question, and realized that the other day I answered another question slightly wrong because I thought that it was the Kernel that took care of that.

Comment: It seems like the answer is that the only manner in which a signal handler can depend at all on which thread it's running in is through `errno`. All other functions which deal with threads or thread-local state are not async-signal-safe. I wonder if `errno` really works properly on glibc though if a signal arrives before the thread finishes initializing its TLS area...

Answer (score 0):

The [POSIX `pthread_create` specification](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_create.html) mandates this from my understanding of:

> The signal state of the new thread shall be initialized as follows:
>
> - The signal mask shall be inherited from the creating thread.
> - The set of signals pending for the new thread shall be empty.

But I don't have enough experience to say that the things are this way in various implementations.

Comment: I think that strictly means that the new thread does not inherit or share pending signals from its parent or creator.

Comment: Indeed. I don't see any way to interpret that statement as saying that the thread shall not receive signals before it's in a consistent state.

Comment: @R - what's the meaning of "a consistent state"?  What's the actual impact of getting a signal before this consistent state and a microsecond after?  Presumably it would still be handled or ignored or whatever.  I am not arguing so much as trying to assess the actual impact.

Comment: @Duck: in the glibc thread start code that I looked at there was a few actions that happened.  One of those was to initialize the current thread's exception handling default catcher (this is done in C code, and is necessary since pthreads are used in C++ {and probably in objective-C too}). I don't know what the rules are for throwing exceptions within signal handlers are, but if this did happen and it was before that code it would not fail as gracefully as it should.

Comment: @Duck: I mean the consistency of any data structures used for managing the thread. Some things that come to mind are access to `errno` (an early signal handler should not crash or overwrite another thread's `errno` when accessing `errno`), `fork` and `pthread_atfork` handlers, and thread-local storage (but this is outside the scope of any current spec).

Answer (score -1):

pthread_create is a blocking call. There is no (new) thread for it to send the signal to before the call, and there *is* a thread to send the signal to *after* the call, thus the thread's ID is returned by the call.

Therefore, I'd conclude that the thread has to be valid and initialized at that time...

Comment: I don't follow. My question is not about `pthread_create` sending a signal to the new thread, but about other signals (generated by other threads in the same process, other processes, or the kernel) being delivered to the new thread before it's initialized.

Comment: This is not true, pthread_create is (commonly) not an atomic call.